# Favorite tag question highlighting not working in some cases

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, tag-watching

Ever since I've been using SO, I've always 'known' questions that have a favorite tag to become highlighted (their background becomes yellow in the selection list). However, recently I noticed one of my favorite tags wasn't working.

A little search based picture to make it a little more obvious:
[image]

As you can see I also have no ignored tags, so I don't think there is a conflict there.
Is this a bug, or is this functionality added by something else?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is intentional, you're searching for `[assembly]` which means **all** of your results would be highlighted...we intentionally don't highlight searches or `/questions/tagged/x` type views that are of one of your favorite tags.  The reason the top 2 are highlighted in your screenshot are they match *other* favorite tags you have.

Highlighting is meant to distinguish things of importance, if everything is highlighted, it stops making sense :)

Comment: Good answer, wonder how come nobody noticed this before!